# How to design a website on Django platform?

Tags: python, django

Apologies if my question is misleading. Here's what I mean. In Visual Studio 2010 for example, you could visually design a website or a web application as well as add C# code here and there. How would I design my website without an IDE, just by using Python IDLE and Django platform.

Would I need to use something like Dreamweaver to design the front-end part and then link it with Django? And if that is so, how difficult is the linking process of front-end with back-end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django source code is usually edited in a non-GUI application. So, unless you use the code tab, Dreamweaver will be useless.

That is, unless you create a static HTML file *first* then populate it with dynamic code and separate it into bits.

Answer (score 2):

> just by using Python IDLE and Django platform.

1. Start the webserver
2. Make a model, a controller, and a view.
3. Add data to the db (maybe with the admin model)
4. Load up the page in your browser.
5. Repeat as necessary

But I would recommend a more powerful text editor than idle if you are really going to do develop a whole site.

Answer (score 1):

Even with an IDE you will just be editing text.  Once you get comfortable with the framework, as long as you have debug turned on in your settings, you can do it from any old text editor.

I develop websites using the Eclipse IDE with the Pydev plug-in. The html/css plugin i have installed always seems to break when theres too many Django template tags in the template, so i just use the built in text editor.